# Lineplot with ggplot (categorical x-axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's assume I have a dataset with different dates:

```
d <- c("2019-01-01", 
            "2019-01-02", 
            "2019-01-03",
            "2019-01-04",
            "2019-01-03",
            "2019-04-06",
            "2019-04-03",
            "2019-05-07",
            "2019-05-03",
            "2019-05-03",
            "2019-05-03",
            "2019-05-03",
            "2019-06-03",
            "2019-06-03",
            "2019-06-03",
            "2019-06-03",
            "2019-06-03",
            "2019-06-03",
            "2019-06-03",
            "2019-07-03",
            "2019-07-03",
            "2019-07-04",
            "2019-08-03",
            "2019-09-05",
            "2019-09-03",
            "2019-09-03",
            "2019-09-06",
            "2019-09-08",
            "2019-10-03",
            "2019-11-03",
            "2019-11-03",
            "2019-11-03",
            "2019-11-03",
            "2019-11-03",
            "2019-11-03",
            "2019-12-03",
            "2019-12-03")

df <- data.frame(dates=as.Date(d))
```

Now I'd like to plot a time series with the number of cases for each month:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(dates))+geom_line(stat="bin")
```

Then I've tried to have 12 months on the x-axis. Unfortunately with geom_line() I can only use continuous variables. So, this gives me an error:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(format(dates, "%m")))+geom_line(stat="bin")
```

It works if I use geom_bar(), however, I need lines instead of bars. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be what you´re looking for?

```
# aggregate data
df_plot <- df %>% mutate(month = lubridate::floor_date(dates, "month")) %>% 
                 group_by(month) %>% summarise(count = n())

# plot data
ggplot(aes(x = month, y = count), data = df_plot) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "months", date_labels = "%b \n%Y") +
  labs(title = "Datecount")
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Just one follow-up question: Let's suppose that I have different lines `ggplot(aes(x = month, y = count, group = grp), data = df_plot) + geom_line()`. Is there an easy way to plot a line for the sum of all groups together?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. the easiest woult be # aggregate data
df_plot_grp <- df %>% mutate(month = lubridate::floor_date(dates, "month")) %>% 
  group_by(month, grp) %>% summarise(count = n())

df_plot_all <- df %>% mutate(month = lubridate::floor_date(dates, "month")) %>% 
                 group_by(month) %>% summarise(count = n())


# plot data
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = count), data = df_plot_grp) +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = count), data = df_plot_all) 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "months", date_labels = "%b \n%Y") +
  labs(title = "Datecount")

Answer (score 3):

You are getting some things mixed up here.

`geom_*(stat="bin")` first groups your data according to any `aes(group=?)` you have, then it divides the observed range into 30 bins of equal sizes. When you run the first line, you get a warning:

> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.

If you look at the plot, it hasn't binned according to neither dates nor months, but counted the number of occurences in each of the 30 periods between January 1st and December 3rd. That's roughly a 11 day period.

You will need to do the binning yourself:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% group_by(month=month(dates)) %>% count
# A tibble: 10 x 2
# Groups:   month [10]
   month     n
   <dbl> <int>
 1     1     5
 2     4     2
 3     5     5
 4     6     7
 5     7     3
 6     8     1
 7     9     5
 8    10     1
 9    11     6
10    12     2

df %>% group_by(month=month(dates)) %>% count() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=month, y=n)) + geom_line()
```

The rest, getting the x-axis labels with formatting.

```
df %>% group_by(month=month(dates)) %>% count() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=month, y=n)) + geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:12, labels=month.name)
```

You might throw in a `theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())` for your liking.